# When submitting a cross-domain sitemap, does robots.txt need to list individual XML file, or just the index?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am trying to move a bunch of sitemap files out of my website into a separate site that just has static assets, however I am struggling to understand the cross-site submissions [mentioned on sitemaps.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location).

My sitemap has a lot of URLs so I have around 10 pages. To prove ownership do I need my *robots.txt* to include every single page of the *SiteMap.xml*? Or can it just include the index page? Is the *robots.tx*t way of verifying ownership even still a thing or does Google now just treat ownership as whats verified in Google search console? The documentation around this seems unclear.

Another thing that's unclear to me is regarding the folder and subdomain rules mentioned on sitemaps.org. Do these rules go away when doing a cross-site submission as the folder/subdomain are no longer relevant? E.g. if my sitemaps are on `http://foo.example/SiteMapFiles/SiteMap.xml` and that sitemap has URLs for `http://bar.example/index.html` is this still valid or does the sitemap have to live at `http://foo.example/SiteMap.xml` to follow the folder conventions?

Google just gives me a generic "URL not allowed" error without explaining much more.

What I have right now is. E.g. `www.example.com`, `subdomain.staticAssets.example`. My sitemap files are now as follows.

- `https://subdomain.staticAssets.example/SiteMaps/SiteMap.xml`
- `https://subdomain.staticAssets.example/SiteMaps/SiteMap-1.xml`
- `https://subdomain.staticAssets.example/SiteMaps/SiteMap-2.xml`

I then have `https://www.example.com/robots.txt` with an entry. Sitemap: `https://subdomain.staticassets.example/SiteMaps/SiteMap.xml`

Comment: Despite what it says on sitemaps.org, cross-domain sitemaps aren't widely supported.   You should stick to keeping the sitemaps on your main domain.   They aren't like other static assets that you may need to move for cookie reasons since they are only fetched by bots and not by users as part of page loads.